# Unexpected error: 403 : Forbidden:Bad Request HttpBuilder Get Request

Tags: json, groovy, httpbuilder

I am using this code for GETting JSON objeect from the URL groovy:
when i try it in browser it work very well but whent i try it in my program with httpbuider i have Unexpected error: 403 : Forbidden(meaning that it doesn't a key api but i put it

someone have any idea what is the problems?

my code is :

```
def getJson(Integer id){
def adress = new HTTPBuilder("https://api.XXXY.com")

          def path="/vls/v1/etudiants/${id}?b=my&apiKey=99990"
          //Get request
          adresseServeur.request(Method.GET, JSON) {

              uri.path = path

              headers.Accept = 'application/json'
              // success response handler
              response.success = { resp, json ->
                  retourJson = json
              }

              // failure response handler 
              response.failure = { resp ->
                  println "Unexpected error: ${resp.statusLine.statusCode} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
              }
```

Comment: Do you have to use https?  The browser handles some of that hand-shake connection processing itself but I think some of that falls to you when you are 'outside' the browser.   I have used httpbuilder successfully using GET and POST but never with https, we used http.

Comment: but when i try with https that doesn't work

Comment: I'm not seeing any id variable to replace in the path definition.  Can you try outputting the path variable prior to using it, to make sure it's got the id in it correctly (not the key).

Comment: i try with without the id but it doesn't work